# FileUpload control - error in display file content

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file-upload

I m trying read binary file and save to a variable
but I received 0 as reply in `byte[] buffer` why?

```
Stream FileContent = FileUpload.FileContent;
                int size = Int32.Parse(Request.Headers["Content-Length"]);
                byte[] buffer = new Byte[size];
                FileContent.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                string bin = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                FileContent.Close();
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have .net near me but I used successfully something like this:

Get the file length:

```
fileLength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
```

Get the stream:

```
stream = FileUpload1.FileContent;
```

Read the content:

```
stream.Read(byteArray, 0, fileLength);
```

Hope this helps.